# How to start debugging in VSCode bypassing the step "react-native run-ios"

Tags: visual-studio-code, react-native-tools

I have following configuration in Visual Studio Code which works well.

```
{
      "name": "Debug iOS Hermes - Experimental",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "type": "reactnativedirect",
      "request": "launch",
      "platform": "ios",
      "target": "device",
      "runArguments": [
        "--device",
        "iPhone"
      ]
    }
```

Sometimes, I want to start debugging session directly without step "react-native run-ios", is this possible ?